# Refactoring and Test Driven Development

Tags: unit-testing, refactoring, testing

I'm Currently reading two excellent books "Working Effectively with Legacy Code" and "Clean Code".

They are making me think about the way I write and work with code in completely new ways but one theme that is common among them is test driven development and the idea of smothering everything with tests and having tests in place before you make a change or implement a new piece of functionality.

This has led to two questions:

Question 1:
If I am working with legacy code. According to the books I should put tests in place to ensure I'm not breaking anything. Consider that I have a method 500 lines long. I would assume I'll have a set of equivalent testing methods to test that method. When I split this function up, do I create new tests for each new method/class that results?

According to "Clean Code" any test that takes longer than 1/10th of a second is a test that takes too long. Trying to test a 500 long line legacy method that goes to databases and does god knows what else could well take longer than 1/10th of a second. While I understand you need to break dependencies what I'm having trouble with is the initial test creation.

Question 2:
What happens when the code is re-factored so much that structurally it no longer resembles the original code (new parameters added/removed to methods etc). It would follow that the tests will need re-factoring also? In that case you could potentially altering the functionality of the system while the allowing the tests to keep passing? Is re-factoring tests an appropriate thing to do in this circumstance?

While its ok to plod on with assumptions I was wondering whether there are any thoughts/suggestions on such matters from a collective experience.

Comment: refactoring is behavior preserving - enforced by your tests. So if you change the behavior via your modifications, you're no longer refactoring. For legacy code, you add tests that act like a vice to hold the SUT in place while you improve the design towards testability. These tests can be slow.. the 0.1s guideline is for microtests/unit tests. The reason for that guideline is that you could have thousands of such tiny tests.. if they take 0.1s each, you could be waiting a long time for each time you run them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. That's the deal when working with legacy code. Legacy meaning a system with no tests and which is tightly coupled. When adding tests for that code, you are effectively adding integration tests. When you refactor and add the more specific test methods that avoid the network calls, etc those would be your unit tests. You want to keep both, just have then separate, that way most of your unit tests will run fast.
2. You do that in really small steps. You actually switch continually between tests and code, and you are correct, if you change a signature (small step) related tests need to be updated.

Also check my "update 2" on [How can I improve my junit tests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/589603/how-can-i-improve-my-junit-tests/589620#589620). It isn't about legacy code and dealing with the coupling it already has, but on how you go about writing logic + tests where external systems are involved i.e. databases, emails, etc.

Answer (score 2):

The 0.1s unit test run time is fairly silly. There's no reason unit tests shouldn't use a network socket, read a large file or other hefty operations if they have to. Yes it's nice if the tests run quickly so you can get on with the main job of writing the application but it's much nicer to end up with the best result at the end and if that means running a unit test that takes 10s then that's what I'd do.

If you're going to refactor the key is to spend as much time as you need to understand the code you are refactoring. One good way of doing that would be to write a few unit tests for it. As you grasp what certain blocks of code are doing you could refactor it and then it's good practice to write tests for each of your new methods as you go.

Comment: I'm sorry, but there is every reason in the world a unit test shouldn't use a database socket, read a large file, or any other hefty operation. The chief reason though is that if a test actually did this, it would be an integration test and not a unit test. You're supposed to mock your dependencies so that no real I/O happens and the logic of your code can be tested without relying on, say, your database functioning correctly. That's why an 0.1s goal is totally reasonable, because no real I/O happens.

Answer (score 1):

1. - Yes, create new tests for new methods.
   - I'd see the 1/10 of a second as a goal you should strive for. A slower test is still much better than no test.
2. Try not to change the code and the test at the same time. Always take small steps.

Comment: A slower test may be fine unless it is so slow that people don't run it often enough.

Answer (score 1):

When you've got a lengthy legacy method that does X (and maybe Y and Z because of its size), the real trick is not breaking the app by 'fixing' it.  The tests on the legacy app have preconditions and postconditions and so you've got to really know those before you go breaking it up.  The tests help to facilitate that.  As soon as you break that method into two or more new methods, obviously you need to know the pre/post states for each of those and so tests for those 'keep you honest' and let you sleep better at night.

I don't tend to worry too much about the 1/10th of a second assertion.  Rather, the goal when I'm writing unit tests is to cover all my bases.  Obviously, if a test takes a long time, it might be because what is being tested is simply way too much code doing way too much.

The bottom line is that you definitely don't want to take what is presumably a working system and 'fix' it to the point that it works sometimes and fails under certain conditions.  That's where the tests can help.  Each of them expects the world to be in one state at the beginning of the test and a new state at the end.  Only you can know if those two states are correct.  All the tests can 'pass' and the app can still be wrong.

Anytime the code gets changed, the tests will possibly change and new ones will likely need to be added to address changes made to the production code.  Those tests work with the current code - doesn't matter if the parameters needed to change, there are still pre/post conditions that have to be met.  It isn't enough, obviously, to just break up the code into smaller chunks.  The 'analyst' in you has to be able to understand the system you are building - that's job one.

Working with legacy code can be a real chore depending on the 'mess' you start with.  I really find that knowing what you've got and what it is supposed to do (and whether it actually does it at step 0 before you start refactoring it) is key to a successful refactoring of the code.  One goal, I think, is that I ought to be able to toss out the old stuff, stick my new code in its place and have it work as advertised (or better).  Depending on the language it was written in, the assumptions made by the original author(s) and the ability to encapsulate functionality into containable chunks, it can be a real trick.

Best of luck!

Answer (score 0):

Here's my take on it:

1. No and yes. First things first is to have a unit test that checks the output of that 500 line method. And *then* that's only when you begin thinking of splitting it up. Ideally the process will go like this:

   - Write a test for the original legacy 500-line behemoth
   - Figure out, marking first with comments, what blocks of code you could extract from that method
   - Write a test for each block of code. All will fail.
   - Extract the blocks one by one. Concentrate on getting all the methods go green one at a time.
   - Rinse and repeat until you've finished the whole thing

   After this long process you will realize that it might make sense that some methods be moved elsewhere, or are repetitive and several can be reduced to a single function; this is how you know that you succeeded. Edit tests accordingly.
2. Go ahead and refactor, but as soon as you need to change signatures make the changes in your test first before you make the change in your actual code. That way you make sure that you're still making the correct assertions given the change in method signature.

Answer (score 0):

**Question 1: "When I split this function up, do I create new tests for each new method/class that results?"**

As always the real answer is *it depends*. If it is appropriate, it may be simpler when refactoring some gigantic monolithic methods into smaller methods that handle different component parts to set your new methods to private/protected and leave your existing API intact in order to continue to use your existing unit tests. If you need to test your newly split off methods, sometimes it is advantageous to just mark them as package private so that your unit testing classes can get at them but other classes cannot.

**Question 2: "What happens when the code is re-factored so much that structurally it no longer resembles the original code?"**

My first piece of advice here is that you need to get a good IDE and have a good knowledge of regular expressions - try to do as much of your refactoring using automated tools as possible. This *can* help save time if you are cautious enough not to introduce new problems. As you said, you have to change your unit tests - but if you used good OOP principals with the (you did right?), then it shouldn't be so painful.

Overall, it is important to ask yourself with regards to the refactor do the benefits outweigh the costs? Am I just fiddling around with architectures and designs? Am I doing a refactor in order to understand the code and is it really needed? I would consult a coworker who is familiar with the code base for their opinion on the cost/benefits of your current task.

Also remember that the theoretical ideal you read in books needs to be balanced with real world business needs and time schedules.